# IIS Web.config URL Write Allowing HTTP for Google Analytics

Tags: asp.net, iis, google-analytics, web-config

I am using the following Web.config configuration to redirect all web traffic to use HTTPS and everything seems to be working fine.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Force Https" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="healthcheck.html" negate="true" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO}" pattern="https" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REMOTE_HOST}" pattern="localhost" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="127.0.0.1" negate="true" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="localhost" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />a
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

However, once I implement Google Analytics into my website, I get the following console error:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.example.com/home?utm_expid=122111398-7.nRKNTAQKRlSHzexQZcWu8Q.1' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure font 'http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/mErvLBYg_cXG3rLvUsKT_fesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff2'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Since GA uses HTTP to connect to some of its resources, the resources get blocked by my web application. Is there a way to work around this issue? Perhaps, allow HTTP traffic for a specific domain? If so, how would I go about this?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: The error you posted already shows you what the issue is :  _"but requested an **insecure font** http://fonts.gstatic.com/...."_. Both Google Fonts and Analytics use `https`, so unclear what the "issue" is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some CSS code that was using HTTP to refer to external resources, changing it to HTTPS did the trick.